# How to write a flexible function with python str.replace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, statsmodels

I'm running a piecewise linear model using the statsmodel package.  That said, I'm trying, and failing to manipulate the coefficient titles so I can join to another table.

For example, the below are two coefficients based on two knots in `vehicle_age_model` variable.

```py
bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[0]
bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[1]
bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[2]
```

What I'd like accomplish, is a function that pulls `vehicle_age_model` (or whatever the variable is) and places that in one column.  Then based on the final number inside the square brackets, pull out the knots in place in another column.

In the above example, what I would want is the a dataframe with the following:

```
variable                               Lower    Upper

vehicle_age_model                      0        10
vehilce_age_Model                      10       25
vehicle_age_Model                      25       np.inf
```

The lower will always be zero.  The final upper,  no matter how many knots will always be infinity.

Before building the function, I tried to figure out how to just pull out the variable from the screen.

dataframe name is coeffs.

```
coeffs['index'].str.replace("bs\(np.clip\(\vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf\), degree=1, knots=[10, 25]\)[0]", "vehicle_age_model")
```

Trying different variants of the above, this didn't change a thing.  I'm not sure which direction I should go.

Original Data Frame

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {'index': ['bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[0]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[1]'
        , 'bs(np.clip(vehicle_age_model, 0, np.inf), degree=1, knots=[10, 25])[2]']
        , 'coeff': [.5876, -.1662, -.6380]}


df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
```

Comment: What does your original dataframe look like?

Comment: I added some code for the dataframe @absolutelydevastated